# Qt C++: how to add a simple countdown timer?

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I'm new to Qt C++ and from the few resources I found online I wasn't able to extract only the bit I need to add a countdown timer to a form. I'm not trying to add any buttons or other functionality. Only need to have a timer starting at 1:00 and then decreasing until 0:00 is reached, at which point I need to show some sort of message indicating the user the time is up. I thought maybe adding a label to display the timer would be a simple way to do it (but now sure if I'm right on this).

So far I created a new Qt Application project, added a label to my main form and added some timer code to mainwindow.cpp from what I got at http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/timers.html:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Initialize "countdown" label text
    ui->countdown->setText("1:00");

    //Connect timer to slot so it gets updated
    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateCountdown()));

    //It is started with a value of 1000 milliseconds, indicating that it will time out every second.
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateCountdown()
{
    //do something along the lines of ui->countdown->setText(....);
}
```

In mainwindow.h I added a `QTimer *timer;` as a public attribute and also `void updateCountdown();` as a private slot.

But I'm not exactly sure about how to go on from here. I think the next step is to decrease the timer each second and show that on the "countdown" label (which would be done on the *updateCountdown* slot) but I can't find out how.
I'm also not sure how to trigger a message (maybe on a QFrame) when the countdown gets to 0:00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [QTimer documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details), the function `updateCountdown()` is called every 1 second in your configuration. So you should decrease one second from your timer every time this function is called and update in the UI. Currently you are not storing your time anywhere, so I suggest you add it as a global **for now**, like `QTime time(0, 1, 0)` [QTime Documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtime.html).

Then inside `updateCountdown()`, call `time.addSecs(-1);` and then `ui->countdown->setText(time.toString("m:ss"));`. Then is easy to check if it is "0:00" and do something else.

I hope this helps

Comment: Maybe instead of _global_, make it a member variable?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Yes, was just thinking of using global for test purpose. Also, stopping/deleting the timer after it finished its objective so it doesn't waste CPU time would be nice.

Comment: I've tried this but I must be doing something wrong, as I do get my timer set to 1:00 but nothing else happens. In the header file I added a `QTime *time = new QTime(0, 1, 0)` as a public attribute (as well as the `QTimer *timer` I already had). In the cpp file I added these two lines in the updateCountdown() slot: `time->addSecs(-1); ui->countdown->setText(time->toString("m:ss"));`. It seems I'm missing something, as nothing seems to be happening. I also tried just declaring a `QTime* time`in header and then `time = new QTime(0, 1, 0);` in cpp. I didn't attempt the "when it gets to 0:00" yet.

Comment: You could check if the `updateCountdown()` is actually being called every second by printing the `time->toString("m:ss")`. If it's being called and the output is right, maybe the ui is not being updated correctly.

Comment: Well, finally got it to work but I wasn't able to use the QTime constructor. So instead I declared a public `QTime time` object in my header file and then, in the MainWindow constructor I used `time.setHMS(0,1,0)` to initialize it. Then, like @LucasMota said, I called `time=time.addSecs(-1)` and `ui->countdown->setText(time.toString("m:ss"))` within my updateCountdown() slot. I also change label initialization to `ui->countdown->setText(time.toString("m:ss"))` in the MainWindow constructor. Thanks.